# Flask-APScheduler multiple jobs running at the same time when having multiple workers

Tags: flask, apscheduler

I'm using APScheduler inside my Flask application for periodic jobs (like sending emails). The problem I'm having now is that in my production hosting environment where I'm running multiple workers this causes also to have each worker run it's own seperate job. So for example now I have 8 jobs trying to send the pending emails at the same time. I would like to have only one worker executing jobs. Is there a way on achieving this and what would be the best practice?

Thanky in advance for all suggestions :)

My job definiton:

```
{
            'id': 'email_notification_service',
            'func': 'application.main.jobs:send_new_notifications',
            'args': (),
            'trigger': 'interval',
            'seconds': int(os.getenv('SCHEDULER_INTERVAL', 60))
}
```